# Cherrypy/Chrome: jquery ajax request pending after 2-3 good requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, cherrypy

I have a client that POSTs a JSON array to a Cherrypy server using an AJAX call. Server modifies the array and sends it back to the client. I can see that after making 2-3 smooth requests, next request is 'pending' (as shown in the XHR tab in Chrome).

I don't know what's so special about the last request that it is pending. 
Is it a server or client issue?

This is the server side:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def check_multiple(self):
    input_json = cherrypy.request.json
    futures = []
    [futures.append(pool.submit(checkEntry, entry)) for entry in input_json]
    output_json = []
    [output_json.append(entry.result()) for entry in as_completed(futures)]
    return output_json
```

client:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: address,
    data: JSON.stringify(entry_list),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // work
    }
});
```

EDIT:

OK I've established a pattern. I can send to server 3 POST requsts where each request JSON is:

```
[
    {'name':name_1, 'status': status_1},
    {'name':name_2, 'status': status_2},
    {'name':name_3, 'status': status_3}
]
```

Total of 9 entries. The 4th request hangs. 
Or, I can send 9 POST requests where each requst JSON is:

```
[
    {'name':name_1, 'status': status_1}
]
```

Total of 9 entries, the 10th request hangs. It must be something with the JSON I'm sending and it's length.

Cherrypy access log of the last 3 POSTs:

```
10.184.67.78 - - [07/Feb/2017:03:55:28] "POST /lab/check_multiple HTTP/1.1" 200 124 "http://server-address.com/lab/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"
10.184.67.78 - - [07/Feb/2017:03:55:34] "POST /lab/check_multiple HTTP/1.1" 200 124 "http://server-address.com/lab/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"
10.184.67.78 - - [07/Feb/2017:03:55:40] "POST /lab/check_multiple HTTP/1.1" 200 125 "http://server-address.com/lab/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen in other browsers such as Firefox?

Comment: Yes, the same behavior. 3 good requests and 4th request pending

Comment: What is your OS? This may be Windows-specific. And also please share the logs of the cherrypy app.

Comment: @webKnjaZ, client is windows, server is linux. I attached the access log, error log is empty

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Popup blocker was throttling requests.